# Datatable populated by null, not by JSON

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

**Summary**

I'm trying to populate a datatable with a javascript array containing JSON.  I'm looping through and creating the array with JSON inide.  When I pass this back to the Datatable, it correctly counts the rows, but does not populate them.

You can see this in the screen capture below.  The data below the table is the array being outputted onto the screen.

[image]

**Code Snippets**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#content').append( '<br><table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="display" id="example"></table>' );
    $('#example').dataTable({
         "aaData" : x, // ARRAY CONTAINING JSON
         "aoColumns": [         
            { "sTitle": "ID", "mData" : "ID", sDefaultContent: "n/a" },
            { "sTitle": "Status", "mData" : "status", sDefaultContent: "n/a" },
            { "sTitle": "Date", "mData" : "date", sDefaultContent: "n/a" }
            ]
    });
});
```

I passed the JSON through http://jsonlint.com/, which came up fine.

**Example JSON**

```
{"ID":"TEST","status":"TEST","date":"TEST"}
```

Each JSON string in the array represents a row in the datatable.

**Some Testing**

Manually putting in the JSON works fine, like so...

```
"aaData" :
        [
        {"ID":"test","status":"test","date":"test"},
        {"ID":"test","status":"test","date":"test"},
        {"ID":"test","status":"test","date":"test"},
        {"ID":"test","status":"test","date":"test"},
        ],
```

[image]

**Final Thoughts**

So my array seems to be outputting correctly, and the Datatable seems to take the JSON manually.  Somewhere inbetween, it is not working.  My thoughts are either on the JSON formatting or the way you pull an array with JSON inside.  aaData: doesn't seem to be handling it right.

I'll be happy to answer any more questions or post more code/pics.  Thanks

Comment: Screen shots aren't showing up. Trying to fix..

Comment: I can see them just fine.

Comment: Thanks.  I think my internal network blocks imgur.

Comment: *"Manually putting in the JSON works fine, like so..."* that isn't json. JSON is a string; nothing more, nothing less. You have to parse the JSON into an array or object to be able to do anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

aaData is an array of array. So aaData should look more like:

```
x = [["test", "test", "test"],["id", "status", "date"],["123", "456", "789"]];
```

If you want to create this from your data:

```
//jsonList = you array of json objects
x = [];
for(var i = 0; i < jsonList.length; i++){
    x.push([jsonList[i].ID, jsonList[i].status, jsonList[i].date]);
}
```